# how to find similar strings within a data

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
df<- structure(list(A = structure(c(7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("", "P42356;Q8N8J0;A4QPH2", "P67809;Q9Y2T7", 
"Q08554", "Q13835", "Q5T749", "Q9NZT1"), class = "factor"), B = structure(c(9L, 
8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("P62861", "P62906", 
"P62979;P0CG47;P0CG48", "P63241;Q6IS14", "Q02413", "Q07955", 
"Q08554", "Q5T749", "Q9UQ80"), class = "factor"), C = structure(c(9L, 
8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "P62807;O60814;P57053;Q99879;Q99877;Q93079;Q5QNW6;P58876", 
"P63241;Q6IS14", "Q02413", "Q16658", "Q5T750", "Q6P1N9", "Q99497", 
"Q9UQ80"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I want to count how many elements are in each columns including those that are separated with a ; , for example in this case

first column has 9, second column has 12 elements and the third column has 16 elements. then I want to check how many times a element is repeated in other columns . for example

```
string      number of times       columns
Q5T749           2              1,2
```

then remove the strings which are seen more than once from the df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to start by re-organizing the data into a form that is more convenient to work with. The `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages are useful for that sort of thing.

```
library(tidyr)
df$index <- 1:nrow(df)
df <- gather(df, key = 'variable', value = 'value', -index, na.rm = TRUE)
df <- separate(df, "value", into = paste("x", 1:(1 + max(nchar(gsub("[^;]", "", df$value)))), sep = ""), sep = ";", fill = "right")
df <- gather(df, "which", "value", -index, -variable)
```

Once you do that counting each element is easy:

```
addmargins(t(table(df[, c("variable", "value")])), margin = 2)
```

Dropping duplicates is also easy.

```
df <- df[!duplicated(df$value), ]
```

If you really want to put the data back into the original for you can (though I don't recommend it).

```
df <- spread(df, key = "variable", value = "value")
library(dplyr)
summarize(group_by(df, index), 
          A = paste(na.omit(A), collapse = ";"), 
          B = paste(na.omit(B), collapse = ";"), 
          C = paste(na.omit(C), collapse = ";"))
```

Comment: I liked and accepted your answer. can you please add some information for each function so that I will learn what you did? again thanks

Comment: @nik The documentation will explain how these functions work better than I can. `gather`, `separate`, and `spread` are from the `tidyr` package; `group_by` and `summarize` are from dplyr.

Answer (score 1):

For the count of elements in each column use this

```
sapply(df,function(x) length(unlist(sapply(strsplit(as.character(x),"\\s+"),strsplit,split=";"))))
```

For counting the repetition use this

```
words <- lapply(df,function(x) unlist(sapply(strsplit(as.character(x),"\\s+"),strsplit,split=";")))
dup_table <- table(unlist(words))
dup_table
```

There is a very bad approach to remove the repetition

```
pat <- names(dup_table)[unname(dup_table)>1]
for(i in pat)
 df <- as.data.frame.list(lapply(df,function(x) gsub(pattern = i,replacement = "",x)))
```

But, there is only one problem. It will replace all the occurences of a particular pattern.

Comment: thanks do you have any solution for my main question ?